# Visual Studio 2017 на Windows 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Собрался изучать C# по книге. В книге не рассказывалось как и что настраивать. Зашел сам скачал бесплатную версию Visual Studio Community 2017 с официального сайта. После установки указал C#. У компоненты указанные по умолчанию. У меня Windows 7/

Теперь запускаю мне нужно выбрать шаблон Console App. Его там не было, нашел что можно создать через простой "пустой" шаблон. В конце концов оказалось что пакеты SDK установлены только для Windows 10 и создать шаблон проекта не возможно. Зашел в установку компонентов, там вообще нету для Windows 7.

Что мне делать, как работать с Windows 7?

Не много бомбануло от того что я же качал с Windows 7, качал версию для учащихся студентов и так далее. И это среда разработанная именно для той ОС на которой я сижу не могла автоматом определить или чего подсказать что вот вы ставите на семерку значит вам мы предложим установить такие то файлы и компоненты, ибо у вас не запустится Windows SDK 10. Но нет там по умолчанию было сказано установить это и то и в итоге нельзя нечего разработать. Это как если бы я зашел с макбука и установил с AppStore какое-нибудь приложение для Windows 8 причем успешно с инструкциями что нажать туда сюда, а при запуске сказало что нет вы не можете его использовать здесь!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Запустите Visual Studio Installer.
2. Под Visual Studio Community 2017 три кнопки - обновить, запустить и дополнительное меню (три горизонтальных полоски). Выберите дополнительное меню, в нём выберите пункт "Изменить".
3. В открывшемся окне выберите те шаблоны, которые Вам нужны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот нету там под Windows 7, может мне нужно скачать VS 2015?

Comment: что значит "под Windows 7"? Галочку "Разработка классических приложений" поставили?

Comment: Ура! Спасибо.Заработало!

Comment: @ИнокентийВас: Если помогло, отметьте ответ зелёной галочкой (слева).